# swagger object as payload validation using Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, openapi, joi

I have an API which has to validate OpenApi specifications. I get the payload in OpenApi format like below:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "description": "This is a sample server Petstore server. You can find out more about Swagger at http://swagger.io",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "test swagger",
        "termsOfService": "http://swagger.io/terms",
        "contact": {
            "name": "contactname",
            "url": "http://www.swagger.io/support",
            "email": "email"
        },
```

I tried to validate each one of payload using Joi like

```
 swagger: Joi
          .string()
          .valid("2.0")
          .required(),
```

I felt little difficult in parts like consumes, produces. Is there any simpler way to validate a swagger file or OpenAPI specs? like using any packages for validating?

Comment: did you find out a solution to this?